# Trouble setting $length; only produces one result and doesnt loop through For loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I am having a bit of a problem with the following code, instead of looping through 20 times it just loops through once:

```
$length = min($length, 20);
for ($i=0; $i<=$length; $i++)
  {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title') 
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

  echo ($item_title);

   }
```

I need the loop to look through an RSS feed and display 20 items, but not spit out non-object errors if there is less than 20 items.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, what value does `$length` have initially?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `$length` is 0 initially, and the `min()` of 0 and 20 is 0, so the loop only continues while `$i <= 0`.

Comment: Makes sense. So how do I fix it? I need to go through this loop 20 times or less. Sometimes the feed only has for example 3 items, and when running without $length spits out non-object errors if the items are less than 20.

Comment: You didn't provide much information about what `$length` is supposed to be, so I can't really tell you how to fix it.  If `$x` is a `DOMNodeList` then maybe you meant to do `$length = min($x->length, 20);`

Comment: Im trying to set $length in a effort to stop "Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object" which is what I get if the RSS feed has less than 20 items. If there is a way to do it without $length I am happy to do that. Basically I want the loop to display all RSS items up to a maximum of 20. So if the feed has 6 items, display 6 items. If the feed has 46 items, display the first 20. 

And for the record, your solution does show up to 20 items, but once again, if the feed has less than 20 I get the "non-object" error.

Comment: Well that's an entirely different problem, most likely caused by your use of `<=` as your loop condition operator.  When iterating a collection of `n` elements, you want do `n` iterations.  If an array has 3 elements and you do `for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++)` then you're going to do 4 iterations (`$i = 0, 1, 2, 3`), and the last iteration will fail.  Use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Also, please mark the answer correct if you found this helpful.

Comment: The problem is that I dont know how many items there are, so I dont know what to limit n to, which is why i get the non-object errors.

Comment: You ***do*** know how many items there are: `$x->length`.  If `$x->length` is 5, meaning there are 5 nodes to iterate, then you you want to iterate 5 times.  If you start at index 0, the beginning node, then you want to iterate up to and including index 4 (`0, 1, 2, 3, 4` = 5 nodes).  If you do `$i <= 5`, and `$i` is initially 0, then the loop will execute *6* times (`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` = 6 nodes).  You need to use the `<` operator.